# Incorrect results for simple 2D transformation

Tags: python, affinetransform

I'm attempting a 2D transformation using the [nudged](https://github.com/axelpale/nudged-py) package.

The code is really simple:

```
import nudged

# Domain data
x_d = [2538.87, 1294.42, 3002.49, 2591.56, 2881.37, 891.906, 1041.24, 2740.13, 1928.55, 3335.12, 3771.76, 1655.0, 696.772, 583.242, 2313.95, 2422.2]
y_d = [2501.89, 4072.37, 2732.65, 2897.21, 808.969, 1760.97, 992.531, 1647.57, 2407.18, 2868.68, 724.832, 1938.11, 1487.66, 1219.14, 672.898, 145.059]

# Range data
x_r = [3.86551776277075, 3.69693290266126, 3.929110096606081, 3.8731112887391532, 3.9115924127798536, 3.6388068074815862, 3.6590261077461577, 3.892482104449016, 3.781816183438835, 3.97464058821231, 4.033173444601999, 3.743901522907265, 3.6117470568340906, 3.5959585708147728, 3.8338853650390945, 3.8487836817639334]
y_r = [1.6816478101135388, 1.8732008327428353, 1.7089144628920678, 1.729386055302033, 1.4767657611559102, 1.5933812675900505, 1.5003232598807479, 1.5781629182153942, 1.670867507106891, 1.7248363641300841, 1.4654588884234485, 1.6143557610354264, 1.5603626129237362, 1.5278835570641824, 1.4609066190929916, 1.397111300807424]

# Random domain data
x, y = np.random.uniform(0., 4000., (2, 1000))

# Define domain and range points
dom, ran = (x_d, y_d), (x_r, y_r)

# Obtain transformation dom --> ran
trans = nudged.estimate(dom, ran)

# Apply the transformation to the (x, y) points
x_t, y_t = trans.transform((x, y))
```

where `(x_d, y_d)` and `(x_r, y_r)` are the 1 to 1 correlated "domain" and "range" points, and `(x, y)` are all the points in the `(x_d, y_d)` (domain) system that I want to transform to the `(x_r, y_r)` (range) system.

This is the result I get:

[image]

where:

```
trans.get_matrix()
[[-0.0006459232439068067, -0.0007947429558548157, 6.534164085946009], [0.0007947429558548157, -0.0006459232439068067, 2.515279819707991], [0, 0, 1]]
trans.get_rotation()
2.2532603497070713
trans.get_scale()
0.0010241255796531702
trans.get_translation()
[6.534164085946009, 2.515279819707991]
```

This is the final transformed `dom` values with the original `ran` points overlayed:

[image]

This is clearly not right and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Show the plot of transfomation applied to  `dom`. I think that will give you insight into what the transformation is doing

Comment: Fundamentally, what is happening is that `nudged` is finding a local minimum for the optimization rather than the absolute minimum that clearly

Comment: @MadPhysicist see updated question please. If the issue is that it is getting stuck in a local minimum, then I guess that's it. I can see no way to tell `nudged` to keep looking or anything similar.

Comment: For reference, 2.253...rads ~= 129.1 deg. I totally believe that the transormation is being applied correctly

Comment: could you do a plot ovelaying `ran` and `transformation(dom)`? I'd like to see what is special about that configuration. Let me take a look at the library code, and I may have a way out for you. Initial guesses are everything in least-squares.

Comment: @MadPhysicist updated with the plot you requested.

Comment: Thanks. I don't think that's the right plot. I was looking for `trans.transform(dom)` and `ran`, but it looks like you plotted `trans.transform((x, y))` and `ran`

Comment: Sorry, fixed now.

Comment: Thanks, I'm working on an issue to the dev. I'll probably end up making a PR eventually.

Comment: That'd be great!

Comment: Here is the issue: https://github.com/axelpale/nudged-py/issues/3. I may just get carried away and implement a fix if I can diagnose it in the next half hour or so.

Comment: I figured out your problem. Answer coming shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure out your issue. It is simply that `nudge` has somewhat problematic notation, which is poorly documented.

The `estimate` function accepts a list of coordinate pairs. You effectively have to transpose `dom` and `ran` to get this to work. I suggest either switching to numpy arrays, or using `list(map(list, zip(...)))` to do the transpose.

The `Transform.transfom` method is extremely restrictive, and requires that the inner pairs be of type `list`. Not `tuple`, not any other sequence, but specifically `list`. Your attempt to call `trans.transform((x, y))` only happened to work by pure luck. `transform` assessed that the first element is not a list, and attempted to transform `(x, y)` as a pair of integers. Luckily for you, numpy operators are vectorized, so you can process an entire array as a single unit.

Here is a working version of your code that generates the correct plots using mostly python:

```
x_d = [2538.87, 1294.42, 3002.49, 2591.56, 2881.37, 891.906, 1041.24, 2740.13, 1928.55, 3335.12, 3771.76, 1655.0, 696.772, 583.242, 2313.95, 2422.2]
y_d = [2501.89, 4072.37, 2732.65, 2897.21, 808.969, 1760.97, 992.531, 1647.57, 2407.18, 2868.68, 724.832, 1938.11, 1487.66, 1219.14, 672.898, 145.059]

# Range data
x_r = [3.86551776277075, 3.69693290266126, 3.929110096606081, 3.8731112887391532, 3.9115924127798536, 3.6388068074815862, 3.6590261077461577, 3.892482104449016, 3.781816183438835, 3.97464058821231, 4.033173444601999, 3.743901522907265, 3.6117470568340906, 3.5959585708147728, 3.8338853650390945, 3.8487836817639334]
y_r = [1.6816478101135388, 1.8732008327428353, 1.7089144628920678, 1.729386055302033, 1.4767657611559102, 1.5933812675900505, 1.5003232598807479, 1.5781629182153942, 1.670867507106891, 1.7248363641300841, 1.4654588884234485, 1.6143557610354264, 1.5603626129237362, 1.5278835570641824, 1.4609066190929916, 1.397111300807424]

# Random domain data
uni = np.random.uniform(0., 4000., (2, 1000))

# Define domain and range points
dom = list(map(list, zip(x_d, y_d)))
ran = list(map(list, zip(x_r, y_r)))

# Obtain transformation dom --> ran
trans = estimate(dom, ran)

# Apply the transformation to the (x, y) points
tra = trans.transform(uni)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2)
ax[0][0].scatter(x_d, y_d)
ax[0][0].set_title('dom')

ax[0][1].scatter(x_r, y_r)
ax[0][1].set_title('ran')

ax[1][0].scatter(*uni)
ax[1][1].scatter(*tra)
```

I left in your hack with `uni`, since I did not feel like converting the array of random values to a nested list. The resulting plot looks like this:

[image]

My overall recommendation is to submit a number of bug reports to the `nudge` library based on these findings.

Comment: Thank you Mad! That's a lot of work you went into, and you are correct, those are a *lot* of restrictions. Unfortunately, using your fix I've found that this package produces a **very** low quality transformation. I had much more luck with this function I found while researching this afternoon: [Affine_Fit()](https://elonen.iki.fi/code/misc-notes/affine-fit/)

Comment: @Gabriel. I fixed some of the messed up text. My desktop is behind a firewall that apparently likes to reorder text.